# submit fails after input is removed from form (in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

EDIT: I simplified the example to use text inputs. Same error. Form fails to submit when an input is removed from the form.
EDIT: Duplicated in Firefox 14. Chrome does not have same behaviour.

I have a multiple file upload form with jquery to add and remove file input elements from the form. If I remove one of the inputs the form.submit() function does not proceed. Below is simplified code using "text" inputs. And a Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/carbontax/rMMuE/

```
    <form id="form-foo" method="POST">
        <div id="input-container-container">
       </div>
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="add-text-input" value="ADD TEXT INPUT">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

Script

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $('#form-foo').submit();
    });

    $("#add-text-input").click(function() {
        var div = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'input-container'
        }).append($('<button/>', {
            'class': 'delete-text-input',
            html: "X"
        }));
        var input = $('<input/>', {
            type: 'text',
            name: 'texts',
            'class': 'input-text'
        }).appendTo(div);
        div.appendTo($('#input-container-container'));
    });

    $('#form-foo').on('click', 'button.delete-text-input', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Did you check for JS errors? If you're removing elements from the form, but not removing any JS code that specifically deals with those elements, you could end up with a bunch of errors.

Comment: There are no errors. According to jquery docs. $.remove() removes all handlers as well as the HTML from the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satya Teja had a helpful suggestion to put the submit button inside the form, but I don't know why it works. In my case I need to submit the form indirectly, based on the outcome of another event. So here is the solution.

HTML: add a hidden submit button inside the form

```
    <form id="form-foo" method="POST">
        <div id="input-container-container">
       </div>
       <!-- workaround to allow submit after deleting a form element -->
       <input type="submit" id="form-foo-submit" style="display: none"/>
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="add-text-input" value="ADD TEXT INPUT">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

Script. Instead of calling submit() on the form, call click() on the hidden submit button. Works in Firefox, Chrome and even IE6

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        // Instead of calling $('#form-foo').submit()
        $('#form-foo-submit').click();
    });

    $("#add-text-input").click(function() {
        var div = $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'input-container'
        }).append($('<button/>', {
            'class': 'delete-text-input',
            html: "X"
        }));
        var input = $('<input/>', {
            type: 'text',
            name: 'texts',
            'class': 'input-text'
        }).appendTo(div);
        div.appendTo($('#input-container-container'));
    });

    $('#form-foo').on('click', 'button.delete-text-input', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

keep submit inside the form not outside..

```
<form id="form-foo" method="POST">
        <div id="input-container-container">
        </div>

    <input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

submit

Comment: This is not suitable. I am simplifying my example. Submit is called on the form externally.

Comment: +1 This was a helpful suggestion even though I cannot use it as is because I need to call submit() from outside the form. I still want to know why the submit() function stops working when an input is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Since your inputs are on the outside of the form, none of them are submitted. Make sure all the data that you want to send are *between* the form tags.

Comment: Incorrect, TurdPile. Inputs are added inside the form. Note this line:  div.appendTo($('#input-container-container'));  But it is a funny name.